# FAILED | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/DocWriteRequest

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

following this document of kafka-connect-elasticsearch
https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/kafka-to-elasticsearch README.md file
encountered the following error when creating the sink connector in ksql
using **docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0**
faced similar issue when using **7.11.0** version as well

```
   ksql> describe connector SINK_ELASTIC_TEST_01;
   
   Name                 : SINK_ELASTIC_TEST_01
   Class                : io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
   Type                 : sink
   State                : RUNNING
   WorkerId             : kafkaconnect:8083
   
    Task ID | State  | Error Trace
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0       | FAILED | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/DocWriteRequest
           at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:56)
           at io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkTask.start(ElasticsearchSinkTask.java:48)
           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:308)
           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:238)
           at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
           at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
           at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
           at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
           at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.DocWriteRequest
           at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
           ... 11 more
```

can anyone suggest whats wrong here

Comment: The error is in the connector classpath, not the Elasticsearch container, so what version of that are you using?

Comment: I have tested with kafka-connect-elasticsearch-11.0.3 version, I have placed this jar in /usr/share/java/Kafka path in Kafka connect container

Comment: When I do the get request on kafkaconnect for connector plugins , it displays the ElasticsearchSinkConnector class, which means jar is placed correctly

Comment: You need more than just one jar. Again, I don't think you're following the guide exactly as written... Why not use confluent-hub install ([like the guide does](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/kafka-to-elasticsearch/docker-compose.yml#L104))?